# how to make curl works with https in android devices

Tags: android, openssl, libcurl

curl version is 7.78.0
openssl version is 1.1.1k

I ran a sample code to test.
The certificates path on Android is /system/etc/security/cacerts

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_.get(), CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_.get(), CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/system/etc/security/cacerts");
```

one more thing, i use a pem file, put it in this path.
set it to curl through CURLOPT_CAINFO. it works well.

but when i use CURLOPT_CAPATH, no matter it has the pem file or not, it doesn't work.

i have seen this :[How to make SSL peer_verify work on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253823/how-to-make-ssl-peer-verify-work-on-android/66926685#66926685)

try :
1.build with -DCURL_CA_PATH=/system/etc/security/cacerts
2.modify the by_dir.c at openssl source X509_NAME_hash to X509_NAME_hash_old

both dont work.

Comment: Why do you look for the info on SO, whereas the complete information is on the manual page [CURLOPT_CAPATH](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAPATH.html): **the certificate directory must be prepared using the OpenSSL `c_rehash` utility.**

Comment: thank you for replay.  @273K   You reminded me of the overlooked tip.  However, I didn't find any relevant tutorials on curl's official website, and I don't know how to do c_rehash. hope you can help

Comment: seems i need to use openssl  re_hash to deal with the file in /system/etc/security/cacerts/  but how to do it throught code  not to use cmd line.